# When Google login is enabled in the web view, [GSI_LOGGER]: The given origin is not allowed for the given client ID

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, webview, google-signin

When Google login is enabled in the web view, `[GSI_LOGGER]: The given origin is not allowed for the given client ID` occurs.

[image: 1]

I also set up localhost for Authorized JavaScript origins.

When I press the rendered Google sign-in button in the web view, the backend outputs `[GSI_LOGGER]: The given origin is not allowed for the given client ID` and there is no response.
On the PC web, if you press the rendered Google login button, a Google account selection pop-up will appear, and you can log in by selecting an account. I want this process to happen in the web view as well.

This code works with next.js and is written as:

```
export const GoogleLogin = () => {
  async function handleCredentialResponse(response) {
    const responsePayload = await parseJwt(response.credential); //Encoded JWT ID token

    localStorage.setItem("google_user", JSON.stringify(responsePayload));
    localStorage.setItem("provide", "google");

    console.log("ID: " + responsePayload.sub);
    console.log("Full Name: " + responsePayload.name);
    console.log("Given Name: " + responsePayload.given_name);
    console.log("Family Name: " + responsePayload.family_name);
    console.log("Image URL: " + responsePayload.picture);
    console.log("Email: " + responsePayload.email);
  }

  //user Info decode
  function parseJwt(token) {
    var base64Url = token.split(".")[1];
    var base64 = base64Url.replace(/-/g, "+").replace(/_/g, "/");
    var jsonPayload = decodeURIComponent(
      atob(base64)
        .split("")
        .map(function (c) {
          return "%" + ("00" + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
        })
        .join("")
    );

    return JSON.parse(jsonPayload);
  }

  function componentDidMount() {
    const googleScript = document.createElement("script");
    googleScript.src = "https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client";
    googleScript.async = true;
    googleScript.defer = true;
    document.head.appendChild(googleScript);

    googleScript.onload = function () {
      google.accounts.id.initialize({
        client_id: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_G_CLIENT_ID,
        callback: handleCredentialResponse,
      });
      google.accounts.id.renderButton(
        document.getElementById("buttonDiv"),
        { type: "icon", theme: "outline", size: "large" } // customization attributes
      );
    };
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    componentDidMount();
  }, []);

  function onClickGooglelogin() {
    // google.accounts.id.prompt(); // also display the One Tap dialog
    document.querySelector('[aria-labelledby="button-label"]').click();
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div
        className={style.snsBtn}
        style={{ background: "#fff", border: "1px solid #DFE5EC" }}
        onClick={onClickGooglelogin}
      >
        <Image src={`/images/icon/google.svg`} width={25} height={25} />
      </div>
      <div id="buttonDiv" style={{ display: "none" }}></div>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: try removing  the one with the port. you should only need http://localhost for development testing.

Comment: Thank you for answer. But that answer didn't solve my problem. 